# What material can I use in place of vinyl chair strapping?

Tags: patio

I have an aluminum chair with vinyl straps that I recently replaced.

I don’t like the vinyl straps (plus they’re stretched already), so I’d like to replace with something else.

What do you recommend to replace the straps?
[image]

Comment: How are the vinyl straps currently attached? Can you add a pic of the back side?

Comment: Is it your intent that the chair should be left outside in the weather? That affects possible strap replacement options rather strongly - I like cotton canvas webbing, but it will rot anywhere moderately (or more) wet.

Comment: It will remain outdoors in very harsh and hot weather.

Comment: My mother-in-law crocheted new a seat and back for a chair just like that.  If you're a fan of yarn that's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have purchased 1” wide rolls of nylon strap. I think it is rated at 500 lb., so it would be plenty strong enough and work similar to our chairs.

The only caveat is the nylon stays wet for a day or so after a rain (a big deal in Oregon) if you have cushions it may not be a problem. I am thinking about painting the straps so the paint will seal the webbing but it is very strong.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of webbing used in the old style folding lawn chairs (as opposed to the collapseable "camp chair" that fits into a bag that everyone uses when watching their kids at sporting events these days). Seems about perfect to me.